# Which attribute clear the floated columns?

Tags: css, css-float, overflow

Having the code

```
<style>
    .col{ float:left; width:50%}
    </style>
    <div class="grid">
    <div class="col">column1</div>
    <div class="col">column2</div>
    </div>
```

Which attribute clear the floated columns if applied to "grid" element?
The answer should be 'overflow:hidden', but I can't understand the explanation.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to add clear to your `.grid` CSS.
`clear: left;` or `clear: both;`

### OR

If you're trying to remove the `float: left;` from `.col` that reside in `.grid` you can do..

`.grid > .col { float: none; }`

Answer (score 0):

found the explanation, adding the style overflow:hidden to the div.grid element works like clear:both, cutting the content under the 2 columns.

```
<style>
.col{ float:left; width:50%}
.grid {overflow:hidden}
</style>
<div class="grid">
<div class="col">column1</div>
<div class="col">column2</div>
<div class="col">column3</div>
<div class="col">column4</div>
<div class="col">column5</div>
</div>
clear
```